# Writing down a function to select first available date in a custom calendar, using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is the URL of page: https://cfapp.staticso2.com/1231231123

In my automation code, I am trying to write a function that will select the first available date from a custom calendar.

Dates may be unavailable, so I need to keep on switching the months in calendar until I get the first available date.

Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: The first available date as in the very first date that shows on the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Find all available date element in calendar. And use `findElements` to avoid NoElementFound exception. Check count for element, if it is greater than zero, then you have available data, click on it. Else navigate to next month and search again

```
// set flag for date found or not
 boolean dateFound = false;
 do{   
    //look for if available date element  
     List<WebElement> availableDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='week ng-scope']/button[contains(@tabindex,'0')][1]"));
            //if available date is present then click on 1st available date
            if(availableDates.size()>0)
            {
              for(WebElement date : availableDates)
              {
                date.click();
                break;
              }
            }
            // if not available then click on next arrow button
            else
            {
              WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='NextPeriod']"));
              dateFound = true;
            }
//continue till date is found
}while(dateFound);
```